# Microsoft Word / Outlook trims leading space

Tags: html, ms-word, outlook, editor, trim

I send SQL to interested parties via Outlook as HTML, with Word as the editor.

I like to format my SQL using spaces, rather than tabs.

When I paste the SQL into the editor, formatting is spot on.
But the 'sent' version removes leading spaces.

For example:

```
Select
 *
From
 Employees
```

becomes

```
Select
*
From
Employees
```

Is there an option to prevent this?

Comment: Anyone know how to resolve this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find solution but found workaround - to replace all (and only) leading spaces to **Nonbreaking Spaces**. No needs to replace all ever spaces, only leading ones. This way Outlook will not trim them automatically while sending email.

Before send an email need to

1. select the text, you want to keep leading spaces, and run **Find and Replace** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
2. put into **Find what:** `"^p "` (caret, p, space) or click at the bottom **[Special]** button and choose **Paragraph Mark** and just a space character
3. put into **Replace with:** `"^p^s"` (caret, p, caret, s) or click at the bottom **[Special]** button and choose **Paragraph Mark** and **Nonbreaking Space**
4. now press **[Replace All]** - it will replace leading spaces with **Nonbreaking Spaces** only in selected text, leaving all the rest text unchanged.

---

Result with leading spaces:

```
First without leading spaces
One leading space in this row
No leading spaces again
One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
One leading space in this row
No leading spaces again
One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
  Two leading spaces here
One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
  Two leading spaces here
   Three leading spaces here
```

With leading nonbreaking spaces:

```
First without leading spaces
 One leading space in this row
No leading spaces again
 One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
 One leading space in this row
No leading spaces again
 One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
  Two leading spaces here
 One leading space in this row
  Two leading spaces here
  Two leading spaces here
   Three leading spaces here
```

Comment: lol - holy hell that works but oh my oh my oh my, what a cluster of chaos to implement. Suppose now is as good a time as any to write a macro for Word! Thanks again :)

Comment: dude! how can no one else find this solution useful??? !!!! ??? !!!  I find myself using this almost every day - and I still haven't figure out how to make it a macro !!!

Comment: We forget to upvote.  I almost did myself!  Shame on me and thanks for the reminder.  Unfortunately I hate the solution, but that's not Kostas's fault.

Answer (score 2):

Brief: *Send e-mail as Plain Text to preserve whitespace.*

After spending faaaar too much time trying (and failing) to override HTML paragraph styles, override list styles/characters, and tweak AutoFormat settings in Outlook 2013, the fallback solution may be to send any e-mails for which it is important to preserve whitespace as Plain Text.

One can send an e-mail as Plain Text by:

1. Selecting the Format Text ribbon tab.
2. Selecting Plain Text within the Format group.

Comment: Thank kindly for the reply. And yeah I know how you feel about the time wasting activity this thing turned into.